# Finding a target int value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search

Here's what I have so far:

```
public class ArraySort {

    //method to search the array for an int x

    public int search(int x) {
        int[] testArray = {};
        for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; ++i) {
            if (testArray[i] == x) {
                return (x);
            } else if (testArray[i] != x) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    //main method

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3};
        int x = 3;

        System.out.print(search(x));

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't be discouraged. It looks like the search method should be `static` and `testArray` should either be a static member variable or passed into the `search` method.

Comment: @NomadMaker sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the two `else` statements:

```java
public int search(int x) {
    int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};   // put some numbers here
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        if (testArray[i] == x) {
            return (x);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Think about this: on the first iteration of your original loop, is there any case in which you won't hit a return statement? (hint: the answer is no). And so, your loop will return after just looking at the first number.

Also, your search array was empty?

**Edit: I just noticed you're trying to pass the array in the main method**

So if you want to pass that array to the search method, you need to create a parameter for it:

```java
public int search(int x, int[] testArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
        if (testArray[i] == x) {
            return (x);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3};
    int x = 3;
    System.out.print(search(x), testArray);  // pass the array here

}
```

Comment: This worked after I changed the search method to static.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if the array is sorted or unsorted.

Let's assume that the array is unsorted.  We can search for the index of the element linearly in O(n) time.  The first recommendation is to pass the array to the method search().

```
public int search(int[] testArray, int x) {
    int arrLength = testArray.length;
    int i = 0;
    
    // Traverse in the array
    while (i < arrLength) {
        if (testArray[i] == x) {
            return i;        
        } else {
            i = i + 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

To execute in main method:

```
System.out.println(search(testArray, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to pass testArray as param in your method.
If value was not found in array you can throw exception.
Please see the following example:

```
public static int search(int x, int[] testArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < testArray.length; ++i) {
        if (testArray[i] == x) {
            return (x);
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Element not present in array exception");
}
//main method

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3};
    int x = 3;

    System.out.print(search(x, testArray));

}
```

Moreover you can use java 8

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testArray = {1, 2, 3};
        int x = 3;
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(testArray).filter(value -> value ==x).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Element not present in array exception")));
    }
```